# Как запросить у пользователя файл или папку в C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Нужно, чтобы когда пользователь в программе Winforms нажимал `Открыть`, то открывался проводник, где он мог выбрать файл (не просто файл, а мог выбрать файлы только с определёным расширением). Как это сделать?

Comment: Здравствуйте, почитайте про OpenFileDialog, это как раз то, что вам нужно. Там и фильтры по расширению файла можно настраивать.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прикладываю пример кода, открывающего файлы Excel

```
        var fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm"
        };

        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return;
        }

        var filePath = fileDialog.FileName;

        var dataTableFromExcel = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Перед открытием файла необходимо закрыть его в Excel");

            return;
        }
```